# How do I return an upper field in a JSON with python?

Tags: python, arrays, json, string, objectpath

So, I need some help returning an ID having found a certain string. My JSON looks something like this:

```
{
"id": "id1"
"field1": {
 "subfield1": {
  "subrield2": {
   "subfield3": {
    "subfield4": [
     "string1",
     "string2",
     "string3"
     ]
    }
   }
  }
 }
"id": "id2"
"field1": {
 "subfield1": {
  "subrield2": {
   "subfield3": {
    "subfield4": [
     "string4",
     "string5",
     "string6"
     ]
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Now, I need to get the ID from a certain string, for example:

For "string5" I need to return "id2"

For "string2" I need to return "id1"

In order to find these strings I have used **objectpath** python module like this: **json_Tree.execute('$..subfield4'))**

After doing an analysis on a huge amount of strings, I need to return the ones that are meeting my criterias. I have the strings that I need (for example "string3"), but now I have to return the IDs.

Thank you!!

Note: I don't have a lot of experience with coding, I just started a few months ago to work on a project in Python and I have been stuck on this for a while

Comment: Hey there. Could you provide a code example, so we can reproduce your problem? Also, your JSON is not valid, could you check that again, so that we have the correct structure to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions about the actual structure of the data as being:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "id1",
    "subfield1": {
      "subfield2": {
        "subfield3": {
          "subfield4": [
            "string1",
            "string2",
            "string3"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // And so on
]
```

And assuming that each `string1`, `string2` etc. is in only *one* id, then you can construct this mapping like so:

```py
data: List[dict] # The json parsed as a list of dicts

string_to_id_mapping = {}

for record in data:
    for string in record["subfield1"]["subfield2"]["subfield3"]["subfield4"]:
        string_to_id_mapping[string] = record["id"]

assert string_to_id_mapping["string3"] == "id1"
```

If each string can appear in multiple ids then the following will catch all of them:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

data: List[dict] # The json parsed as a list of dicts

string_to_id_mapping = defaultdict(set)

for record in data:
    for string in record["subfield1"]["subfield2"]["subfield3"]["subfield4"]:
        string_to_id_mapping[string].add(record["id"])

assert string_to_id_mapping["string3"] == {"id1"}
```